# Firebase Cloud Functions - Synchronous Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I´m new to firebase cloud functions. I want to create my index.js as following:

```
exports.countFruits = functions.database.ref("fruits/{FruitID}").onWrite(event =>{

(...)

    var sauces = [];

    let ref = admin.database().ref("sauces");
    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot, prevChildKey){

    let sauce = snapshot.val();
    sauces.push(sauce.id);
    });

// -> USE THE COMPLETED ARRAY FOR NEXT ANOTHER PURPOSE

});
```

So my Problem is, that I want to use the COMPLETED array while it is actually being filled. As a consequence I want to structure my code synchronously so the next function is only executed when all sauce.id are in the array.

How can I code that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you listen to `child_added` events, your handler will be called for each existing child *and* any time a child is added later. So there is no clear moment when all children have been processed.

If you want to handle all current children, you should use a `once("value"` handler, like this:

```
exports.countFruits = functions.database.ref("fruits/{FruitID}").onWrite(event =>{

(...)

    var sauces = [];

    let ref = admin.database().ref("sauces");
    ref.once("value", function(snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach(function(sauceSnapshot) {
        let sauce = snapshot.val();
        sauces.push(sauce.id);
      });
      // -> USE THE COMPLETED ARRAY FOR NEXT ANOTHER PURPOSE
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all thank you! Using this code only gives me an array [undefined] so it seems like the sauce.id isn´t accessible now. Any suggestions?

Comment: The code assumes you have `/sauces/{sauceId}/id`, like your original code did. It's impossible for me to say why that id isn't there, without seeing your actual JSON (as text, no screenshot). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: The database structure looks like that: /sauces/{sauceType}/{sauceID}/id

Comment: In that case the query is missing a level. Again: add a sample snippet to your question as I asked in my previous comment. As an alternative: study some of the [previous questions that handle looping over database results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-database%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+forEach) for inspiration.